# CSS img insert on a:hover:after breaks if two lines

Tags: css, wordpress

My goal is to have an image show to the right of an h3 when a user hovers over it. My code works if the h3 is one line, but it breaks if h3 becomes two or more lines because the image shows still shows immediately after the text instead of after the whole block.

[image: Working Correctly]

[image: Failing]

I am working on a WordPress Template.

I added the absolute positioning to a:hover:after because otherwise the insert of the image shifted the whole h3 element.

```
<div class="col-sm-10 offset-sm-1">
    <div class="blog-entry">
    <?php   
    the_title( '<h3 class="blog-entry-title"> <a href="' . esc_url( 
        get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h3>' ); 
    ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS

```
.blog-entry-title {
    min-height: 75px;
}

.blog-entry-title a {
    color: #232323;
    padding: 15px 90px 15px 15px;   
}

.blog-entry-title a:hover {
    color: #66ccff;
}

.blog-entry-title a:hover:after {
    content:url('https://example/color-burst.png');
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
}
```

Comment: Yes, `::after` content is actually inside the element's containing block, not following it. So the question is, what do you want to happen? Where should the result be? Maybe you can float it instead of positioning absolutely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `background-image` instead of `content:url`. You can adjust the `background-position` instead of moving top the `img` element generated.

I'm using `position:absolute` as well, but only to set the `width` and `height`, so elements stays at the end of the line.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 250px;
}

.blog-entry-title {
    min-height: 75px;
}

.blog-entry-title a {
    color: #232323;
    padding: 15px 90px 15px 15px;

}

.blog-entry-title a:hover {
    color: #66ccff;
}

.blog-entry-title a:hover:after {
  content: '';
  background: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fe/Farm-Fresh_bullet_error.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 40%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="blog-entry">
  <h3 class="blog-entry-title"><a href="#">Hello world</a></h3>
</div>
<div class="blog-entry">
  <h3 class="blog-entry-title"><a href="#">The Best Guacamole Recipe in the World</a></h3>
</div>
<div class="blog-entry">
  <h3 class="blog-entry-title"><a href="#">Goodbye world</a></h3>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```